# Conflict between \lettrine and \justify

Tags: lettrine

When i use `\lettrine` with `\justify`, the indentation is wrong.
Below it's the code used :

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[headheight=13.3338pt,top=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{oldgerm}
\usepackage{calligra}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\calligra}

\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{page \thepage}} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\justify

\section{Introduction}

    \subsection{test}
        \subsubsection{test}
            \lettrine[lines=2, lhang=0.33, loversize=0.25, findent=1.0em]{M}{ea} culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.

            Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \begin{verbatim}
Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
            \end{verbatim}
            Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.

            Mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa, mea culpa.
\end{document}
```

When you just remove `\justify` the indentation is good, but the text isn't properly justify, but when you use `\justify` the indentation is wrong but the text is properly justify.

So what's wrong ?

Comment: If you are the same user as https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134822/samixchoumi  You can ask that your accounts be merged

Comment: I'm but when i've chosen to continue with my current account, that just created this account.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

Justification is the default setting, you should almost never need `\justify`. In this case the problem is

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

which makes the whole document ragged right. Just use

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

and remove the `\justify`

I also added `\title{zzz}` as your test example otherwise generates an error.

[image]

The underlying issue is that if you do want to revert to justification inside a ragged block then the syntax is either `\justifying` or `\begin{justify}..\end{justify}` not `\justify`, just as the standard latex commands for centering are `\centering` or `\begin{center}..\end{center}`  not `\center`.

`\justify` is just the internal implementation of `\begin{justify}` but that is a list environment and  lettrine does not work within a list.

However it is hard to think of any real use for explicit justification in LaTeX as that is the default, and if you switch to ragged right for a specific environment it is very uncommon to need to switch back to justified text within a nested environment.

Comment: Thanks so i removed `\justify` and `[document]` and now i've a justified text. I will now look to remove the automatic indent.

Comment: @Samix `parskip` package perhaps if you want paragraph spacing and no indent